# Emission light in shader node - Blender 2.8B

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

In render preview, the item seems to work. But when hitting F12 to render, the particles are black and no emission is on picture for the particles.

[image: Eevee preview]

on rendering output
[image: Render output Blender 2.8 Beta]

[image]